# How create a copy of an item from a subsite list in a custom list on a parent site?

Tags: sharepoint-server, custom-list, sub-site

How do I create a copy of an item from a subsite list in a custom list on a parent site?

I have a parent site that contains a list, which is also part of a subsite template. Every time I create a subsite, that list is created together. Both lists have exactly the same structure.

I need to create a 2013 workflow, in the model, that every time an item is created, a copy of the item is created in the parent site list.

Could someone help me with this logic and if possible, there is a practical example to present myself, thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use "call HTTP web service" action in SharePoint 2013 workflow platform.

Here is an article about [SharePoint Designer Call HTTP Web Service to create item in other Site (Collection)](https://www.portiva.nl/nl/portiblog/2016/11/03/sharepoint-designer-call-http-web-service-to-create-item-in-other-site-collection) for your reference.